# Javascript onclick event handler on multiple classes

Tags: javascript

How do I click on a class name and invoke a function when I have more than one class?  In my code I have 9 class boxes which I want to call a function each time I click on one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tic Tac Toe Game</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #container {
      width: 303px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 40px;
    }
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    /*#wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
  }*/
    .col {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .col > div:nth-child(-n+1) {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .col > div:nth-child(-n+2) {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .col > div {
      border-right: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .col:last-child {
      border-right: none;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    #wrapper.col * {
      border-right: none;
    }
    .reset {
      clear: both;
    }
    .box {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: grey;
      font-size: 80px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    body {
      font-size: 80%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="reset"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var turnsArray = [];

    function player() {
      alert("hello");
    }

    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    el.onclick = player;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not a single element, so you can't attach event handlers to it directly.
You need to iterate over this collection and set event event handler for each element:

```
items = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
[].forEach.call(items, function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', player);
});
```

*HTMLCollection is not a proper array, so you can't call forEach method on it directly, but you can call forEach on array and pass collection to it.*

Answer (score 0):

`el` gives a HTMLCollection, so you need to iterate and set onclick listener on each, in ES6 you can convert an HTMLCollection into array simply by `[...el]`, so code becomes:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
[...el].forEach(e => e.onclick = player)
```

[<kbd>Fiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mido22/gdquj58f/2/)

Comment: I think, you should clarify your answer for those, who are not familiar with ES6 syntax.

Comment: @AlexeyUkolov updated, i knew I could come up with smaller notation :)

Comment: [Browser support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator) for spread is surprisingly good, event better than arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

[].slice is used to convert the result of call to a new array .So you can use `forEach` then.

```
 var el = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    el_arr = [].slice.call(el);
    el_arr.forEach(function(obj,i){
    obj.addEventListener("click",function(){
        player();
         });
    });
```